# How do I subtract 2 timestamp from a dabase using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

For example, I have 2 dates

```
$start = 2020-08-15 20:39:43;
$end = 2020-08-15 20:59:43;

$total = $end - $start = 10 min;
```

how can I do that?

Comment: echo (new DateTime($end))->diff(new DateTime($start))->format('h');

Answer (score 2):

Use [`timestampdiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

```
select timestampdiff(
    minute,
    '2020-08-15 20:39:43',
    '2020-08-15 20:59:43'
)
```

If your dates are in columns `start_ts` and `end_ts` of table `mytable`, then:

```
select timestampdiff(minute, start_ts, end_ts) diff_minutes
from mytable
```

Comment: the time come from the database as variable

Comment: replace the dates with the columnnames

Comment: @Shahabuddin: just replace the literal dates with the column names - see my updated answer.

Comment: @GMB

$diff_min = ( strtotime( $end_time ) - strtotime( $start_time ) ) / 60 / 60;
$total_time  = $diff_min;

This is the solution to it but thank you for your suggestion